# how do I get which keys are being held at specific time?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I need a way to get all the keys which are being pressed(or held) at a single moment. Alternatively, how can I check the status of a specific key (up or down)? I can't do a loop that waits for input because I need the program to keep running. like, how can I check if the key `a` is currently being pressed or released? I can't use ah 1/int 16h because if two keys are held at the same time one of them doesn't register, and I've tried in al, 60h but how do I use it when multiple keys are being held and I need all of them?

Comment: You detect key presses and releases and keep track of keys which are pressed without being released. See also [osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/PS2_Keyboard).

Comment: For DOS action games you will have to install your own keyboard interrupt and create your own data keeping up-to-date flags for key press/release actions. The `int 16h` is working reasonably OK for simpler things, like one key at the same time, like some kind of "snake" game, etc... `in al,60h` (in the app code, along original BIOS keyboard handler) is generally interfering with the BIOS keyboard interrupt handler, so it works unreliably (it's good enough to detect multiple "esc" hits to exit some app, but not good enough to control something).

Comment: Also the PC keyboard is generally not very friendly to multi-pressed keys, in games which require like 4+ keys pressed at the same time, some keyboards may start to skip presses/releases of certain keys. At least that's how it was back in DOS era and PS2 keyboards, not sure if modern USB ones are better.

Comment: @Ped7g Modern keyboards work the same way in this regard.  Some high-end keyboards are better in this regard (the feature is marketed as *n key roll over* ), but the USB standard doesn't support more than 6 (?) depressed keys at once anyway.

Comment: @fuz: Why does the USB standard care how many keys are down at once?  Does it not just sending key-up / key-down events?  Or does the USB HID (human interface device) protocol say something about the host side not being required to track more key presses without releases?  (I know the name of the protocol from the Linux driver; I don't know anything more :P)  Anyway, I thought this was mostly about the keyboard *internals*, that instead of having a pin for every separate key, they have a kind of grid where each key makes a different combo of connections, and the controller decodes it.

Comment: @PeterCordes USB keyboards don't send messages on their own. You have to poll them for what keys are depressed and the packet format is specified to support up to 6 keys.

Comment: @fuz: Oh right, I forgot that USB is 100% host-driven, so you can't have device-initiated messages.  Only polling.  Is that "6 keys" a total state, or is it a delta change?  i.e. 6 keys changed state since the last poll?  If it's a delta, that would explain how there are gaming keyboards that advertize larger rollover limits.

Comment: @fuz: I checked, and apparently it is a full state (not including modifier keys).  But the protocol limit might not actually be 6: that's just one reading of the standard.  One post on this forum (http://www.microchip.com/forums/m368006.aspx) reports getting 32 simultaneous keys to work, with some details about the spec and protocol.  IDK what the Windows / Linux / OS X drivers accept by default, but vendors of fancy USB keyboards could include special drivers if necessary...